# converting VB linq to c# linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert link query in vb below to C#. I have never previously done vb and linq query before, I have converted to SQL but what would this be in linq c#,

VB script

```
 Dim d = (From p In db.tblkeyPages Join keypagetype In db.tblkeyPageTypes On p.keyPageType Equals keypagetype.keyPageType Where keypagetype.keyPageType = 1 Select p.pageContent).First
```

SQL

```
select d.keyPageType, d.pageContent from dbo.tblkeyPage as d
join (select keyPageType from dbo.tblkeyPageType )as s 
on d.keyPageType = s.keyPageType
where s.keyPageType = 1
```

Comment: Do you have any progress on converting to C#?

Comment: @X.L.Ant: You should try this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good starting point: [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx)

```
var content = (from p in db.tblkeyPages 
               join keypagetype in db.tblkeyPageTypes 
                    on p.keyPageType equals keypagetype.keyPageType
               where keypagetype.keyPageType == 1
               select p.pageContent).First();
```

Also I suggest you to spend time learning C# syntax. As you can see, query looks almost same (just keywords are lower case, because C# is a case-sensitive language)

One more note - if you want to avoid exception, then use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()` when it is possible that no results will be returned by query.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. that link really helped in link query.